# SSL on AWS Postgres RDS

Tags: postgresql, ssl

I was reading this:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL

Step 2 says "Install the certificate in your operating system", but I am able to connect with `psql` without doing anything, and when I do, it says `SSL connection`. Without the servers certificate, how can it do this? Where are public certificates to be kept for a client to check? I've seen things talking about ~/.postgresql, others saying with the rest in /etc/ssl, but I don't see Amazon's anywhere on my system.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a very vague idea of what might have happened here. It is not possible that you can enter the server without a certificate if the server is SSL encrypted.

I had tried [some environment variable setting directly in front of the psql command that loaded the certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62791537/11154841):

```
PGSSLMODE=require PGSSLROOTCERT=server-ca.pem psql -h your_host -U your_user -W -d your_db
```

And that solution turned out to be the right one, but I had another mistake in the command at that time so that I saved the correct settings without knowing.

When I then entered the psql command without any environment variable being set and with the other unrelated mistake being solved, it worked *without* any certificate.

Later, it turned out that the environment variables were the right way to go and that the `pem` certificate is kept in the env var, you do not need to assign it again and again.